# jquery datepicker not working inside <h:form>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui, datepicker

I got datepicker code from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

The source works as such but it does not work (no calendar pops up) inside  tags inside my jsp. The source works fine (popup calendar comes) if the input text is placed outside h:form. I am using eclipse and jsf to develop the page
    
Here is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<h:form>
<h:outputText value="Select date" />
<h:inputText id="datepicker"/>
</h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the console in your web browser to see if JQuery function have been successfuly loaded to your project.

Comment: JQuery functions are loaded as it does work out of h:form tags. I have printed sample text in console after datepicker function is called and that is printed. jquery scripts are hosted online on different server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to see in Firebug or a developer console the real ID of datepicker. JSF adds the form's ID to the element, like "formID:datepicker", so if you do $('#datepicker'), jquery can't find it.

Comment: Please mark it as resolved if this answer helped you.

Comment: I am new to developing web apps. We have ie provided in our systems. in dom explorer, i can see real id of datepicker. What should I do next to make it work??

Comment: i have added id to form and changed #datepicker to formid:datepicker. But that doesnt work too...

Comment: it's #YOURID:datepicker, maybe you forgot #

Comment: Yeah, I have used #myid:datepicker. its a typo mistake in comment as i am posting these comments via mobile...

Comment: Using  "Developer Tools" (F12) try to see after loading the page, if $('#formid:datepicker') return an object not empty.

Comment: Without using #formid before datepicker, the console is printing [object Object] {context: HTMLDocument {...}, jquery: "1.10.2", length: 0, selector: "#datepicker"}. With #formid:datepicker, console says Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: datepicker

Comment: It's beacuse you have to escape ":" with "\\".

Comment: Thankyou, for your quick reply. I did the same inside javascript function (using \\) and it worked. Sorry for my dumbness as I am very new to this stuff...